# How to make Vertex AI multi-label classification AutoML not ignore texts with no labels?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I prepared a training dataset for multi-label classification in JSON Lines format as described in [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/prepare-text#json-lines_1).

My upload file looks like

```js
{
  "textContent": "This text corresponds to 2 labels",
  "classificationAnnotations": [
    {"displayName": "LABEL_1"},
    {"displayName": "LABEL_2"}
  ]
}
{
  "textContent": "This text doesn't correspond to any labels",
  "classificationAnnotations": []
}
// ... and other 5,853 lines
```

Only 1,037 texts have non-empty list of labels.

[image: Training dataset labels]

Other texts are considered "Unlabeled". AutoML ignores unlabeled texts.

[image: AutoML training result]

As a workaround I added an extra label to every text

```js
{
  "textContent": "This text corresponds to 2 labels",
  "classificationAnnotations": [
    {"displayName": "LABEL_1"},
    {"displayName": "LABEL_2"},
    {"displayName": "EXTRA_LABEL"}
  ]
}
{
  "textContent": "This text doesn't correspond to any labels",
  "classificationAnnotations": [
    {"displayName": "EXTRA_LABEL"}
  ]
}
// ... and other 5,853 texts
```

Is there a way to make AutoML use "Unlabeled" texts as texts with 0 labels?

Comment: From what I know there is no way to use unlabeled text, but you could use [Auto ML Natural Language UI](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/beginners-guide) to upload unlabeled text and this applies labels to the text.

Answer (score 1):

We often put the unlabeled text to an all-zero vector for training. This can't be done in Automl for now, I think.